# cannot import name 'image_dataset_from_directory'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to import the following:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB5
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import image_dataset_from_directory
```

And I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5f46c7257169> in <module>
      3 from tensorflow.keras import *
      4 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
----> 5 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import image_dataset_from_directory
      6 import os
      7 import shutil

ImportError: cannot import name 'image_dataset_from_directory'
```

I'm using python3.9, tf-2.6. I also tried to install tf-nightly/keras-nightly, facing the same error. Any idea about how can I solve it? Last week I can ran the code, but now I'm completely stuck.

Comment: `from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory`